# How is a static resource referenced in a XAML collection?

Tags: wpf, xaml, staticresource

If I have static resources defined in XAML such as

```
<x:String x:Key="HelloString">Hello</x:String>
<x:String x:Key="GoodbyeString">Goodbye</x:String>
```

What is the syntax to add them to a XAML collection such as ListBox?

My intent would be to do something like this:

```
<ListBox>
    <x:String Source="{StaticResource HelloString}"/>
    <x:String Source="{StaticResource GoodbyeString}"/>
</ListBox>
```

But I'm missing the correct syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible by using a `ContentPresenter`:

```
<ListBox>
    <ContentPresenter Content="{StaticResource HelloString}"/>
    <ContentPresenter Content="{StaticResource GoodbyeString}"/>
</ListBox>
```